# Ignore any characters with Regular Expression in Node.js Express Router

Tags: node.js, regex, express

I want to achieve the following requirements for Express and Node.js.

A. Capture the specified value from the URL

B. Ignore any characters following the value

example.

```
http://localhost:xxxx/test/123%E3%81%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%86

http://localhost:xxxx/test/456-noise_data
```

To achieve, I planed 1st implementation plan.

```
  //1st.
  app.get(/test\/[0-9]{3}.{0,}/, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.originalUrl)
    res.send('/test\/[0-9]{3}.*/') }
  )
```

You can ignore the strings with ".{0,}" (Requirement B). But, you have to extract the value from req.originalUrl (Requiremnet A).

I planned 2nd implementation plan.

```
  //2nd.
  app.get('/test/:val([0-9]{3}).{0,}', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.val)
    res.send('/test/:val([0-9]{3}).{0,}') }
  )
```

In the 2nd case, you can easily extract value with req.params.val (Requirement B). However, ".{0,}" doesn't work as regular expression. "." means not any character but only "." (Requirement A).

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/EtUZiC/3) help?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.
I need how to use "." notation as regular expression in not /test\/[0-9]{3}.{0,}/ but '/test/:val([0-9]{3}).{0,}' notation style. In general "." means any character. Although, in the '/test/:val([0-9]{3}).{0,}' implementation, "." notation is used for the interpretation to only "." .

Comment: Have you tried escaping the dot (**```\.```**)?

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't correctly work.

Comment: app.get('/test/:val([0-9]{3})\.{0,}', function (req, res)